# ServiceActivator does not receive message from ImapIdleChannelAdapter

Tags: spring-integration

ServiceActivator does not receive messages from ImapIdleChannelAdapter...

JavaMail logs successful FETCH, but MIME messages do not get delivered to SA endpoint... I want to understand what is wrong in my code.

`A7 FETCH 1:35 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODYSTRUCTURE)
* 1 FETCH (ENVELOPE ("Fri....`

Code snippet below:
`
    @Autowired
    EmailConfig emailCfg;

```
@Bean
public SubscribableChannel mailChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public ImapIdleChannelAdapter getMailAdapter() {
    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(emailCfg.getImapUrl());
    mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
    mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
    mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver);
    imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(mailChannel());
    imapIdleChannelAdapter.setAutoStartup(true);
    imapIdleChannelAdapter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mailChannel")
public void receive(String mail) {
    log.warn(mail);
}

private Properties javaMailProperties() {
    Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl", "true");
    return javaMailProperties;
}
```

`

The problem was due to wrong bean initialization. Full version that works OK:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class MyMailAdapter {

@Autowired
EmailConfig emailCfg;

@Bean
public SubscribableChannel mailChannel() {
    log.info("Channel ready");
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public ImapMailReceiver receiver() {
    ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver(emailCfg.getImapUrl());
    mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
    mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
    mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);
    return mailReceiver;
}

@Bean
public ImapIdleChannelAdapter adapter() {
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(receiver());
    imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(mailChannel());
    imapIdleChannelAdapter.afterPropertiesSet();
    return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mailChannel")
public void receive(Message<MimeMessage> mail) throws MessagingException {
    log.info(mail.getPayload().toString());
}

private Properties javaMailProperties() {
    Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
    javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl", "true");
    return javaMailProperties;
}
}
```

Comment: Turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework.integration` to follow the message flow and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Typical error from end-user perspective in this case is like missed `@EnableIntegration` on some `@Configuration` class: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: Thanks Gary, Artem. As you correctly guessed, the problem was related to bean initialization. Added a working sample

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's exactly wrong with your code but I will suggest you few approches that could help you.

1. Firstly I suggest you to use java DSL in java based configuration. It will provide you nice way to directly specific flow of your integration application (and avoid simply mistakes). For example for spliiter and service activator:

   ```
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow yourFlow(AbstractMessageSplitter splitter,  
   MessageHandler handler) {
   return 
   IntegrationFlows
       .from(CHANNEL)
       .split(splitter)
       .handle(handler).get();
   ```

   }
2. Secondly it's generally bad idea to directly specify message type to String. Try something like this (why String?):

   ```
   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mailChannel")
   public void receive(Message<?> message) {
   /* (String) message.getPayload() */
   }
   ```

Maybe it's not a case but let's check it.

Comment: The Imap Idle adapter is not a `MessageSource` (polled adapter); it is a message-driven adapter and does not require an inbound channel adapter annotation.

Comment: How does splitter relates to my question? Any Message payload can be cast to String. Correct type is javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

Comment: Splitter it's only placeholder for java DSL example (it's not directly related). Sounds a little strength - when I created message with org.w3c.dom.Document in payload, and received it in another service with (String) message.geyPayload() - I got  org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.String